# Make Word's Cursor Type (Or More Text Insert) in Non-Italic After Turning Text Italic

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I perform the following code:

```
Dim italicSaveRange As Word.Range
Dim savedItalic As Variant
Dim someRange As Word.Range

Set italicSaveRange = someRange.Duplicate
italicSaveRange.Collapse (WdCollapseEnd)
savedItalic = italicSaveRange.Italic
someRange.Italic = True
italicSaveRange.Italic = savedItalic
```

I expected that any text entered at the cursor or inserted into `someRange` a la:

```
someRange.InsertAfter "Lorem ipsum..."
```

would not be italic (assuming that the formatting was not italic at this position previously, of course.)  But it is.  Help.

---

Based on your suggestion I now have the following, which appears to be working.  It may be a fragile solution, depending on what gets moved around in the meantime (e.g., try typing some italic text into Word, ctrl-i to prepare to use non-italic, but then move the cursor left into the italics and then right out again; the cursor is inserting italic text...), but for my purposes where I am adding text elsewhere (but at a different level of the code so that I cannot access the text to insert at this level) this will probably work.  Thank you.

```
Set italicSaveRange = someRange.Duplicate
italicSaveRange.Collapse (WdCollapseEnd)
savedItalic = italicSaveRange.Italic
someRange.Italic = True
italicSaveRange.InsertAfter SP
italicSaveRange.Characters(1).Italic = savedItalic
italicSaveRange.Characters(1).Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert text into a Word Range object, this text will always (afaik) inherit the formatting of the previous text run.

To work around you should apply the formatting after you inserted the text, i.e.

```
Dim italicSaveRange As Word.Range
Dim savedItalic As Variant
Dim someRange As Word.Range

Set italicSaveRange = someRange.Duplicate
italicSaveRange.Collapse (WdCollapseEnd)
savedItalic = italicSaveRange.Italic
someRange.Italic = True
italicSaveRange.Text = "Lorem ipsum..."
italicSaveRange.Italic = savedItalic
```

If you must insert the text later you could need to insert some dummy text which you replace later.